# Infinite redirect using Mocha, Veloctiy, and Meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor, phantomjs, reactjs, mocha.js

I'm trying to use mocha paired with PhantomJS to run some integration tests without needing to open a new window.  My code looks something like:

```
var waitForAccounts = function(callback) {
  if (Accounts.loginServicesConfigured()) {
    callback();
  } else {
    setTimeout(function() {
      waitForAccounts(callback);
    }, 10);
  }
}

var waitForLogin = function(callback) {
  if (!!Meteor.user()) {
    callback();
  } else {
    setTimeout(function() {
      waitForLogin(callback)
    }, 10);
  }
}

if (!(typeof MochaWeb === 'undefined')){
  MochaWeb.testOnly(function(){
    describe("Menu bar", function(){
      it("should have the correct title", function() {
        expect($('.navbar-brand').html()).to.equal('Lynx');
      });

      describe('when logged in', function() {
        beforeEach(function(done) {
          waitForAccounts(function() {
            if (!Meteor.user()) {
              Meteor.loginWithFacebook({
                loginStyle: 'redirect'
              });
              waitForLogin(function() {
                console.log('User:', Meteor.user());
                done();
              });           
            } else {
              done();
            }            
          });
        });

        it('should have a logout link', function() {
            expect($('#logout').html()).to.exist;
            expect($('#login').html()).to.be.undefined;
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

I'm guessing this has something to do with the code reloading on every page load, which happens when the account logs in (currently there's a proxy that fakes and auto accepts for the fb oauth.)  I'm just not sure how to solve it at this point.

The UI is written using ReactJS and the backend/reactivity is written using Meteor.

Comment: It seems that popups don't work either, as when I switch the login style to popup, it no longer is stuck in an infinite loop, but it the popup doesn't close, so it times out.